# Service Host: Capability Access Manager interfering with Audio Processing script

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, audio, pyaudio

I have a DSP script written in Python that applies a couple of different bi-quad filters to an incoming audio stream and then analyses the output before feeding it through to the output. The script is designed to run in pseudo-real-time, currently operating with a small (still tuning timings for stability, 20ms or less) buffer. It reads and writes to the incoming/outgoing audio stream buffers using the pyaudio libraries.

Every time I run the script, it runs seamlessly for 30-35 seconds before something trips in windows Service Host: Capabilities Access Manager or the Service Host: Local Service (Network Restricted) in charge of Windows Audio. At this point, these 2 processes take up a large percentage of the system processing power (1-2 cores hit for 80% before, all cores pinned at 100% utilisation after). This spike in cpu utilisation causes the script to start missing buffers and hitching constantly.

Have tried disabling the responsible processes but can't run anything audio related with them disabled.

Tried a minimal computation single threaded version of the script that doesn't do anything other than feed through the original audio and it runs ok. What confuses me is that the computing script fails reliably, and doesn't appear to max out even a single thread before the windows processes clamp it down.

Is there anything I can do to stop these windows processes locking up my code in settings etc? Any permissions flags I might need to set? I am considering translating it into C++ or C# to improve efficiency, would that resolve this issue or is it possible it will persist even then? I am also mid-way through setting up a Linux dev environment to bypass this issue for further testing, but eventually will need it to run seamlessly in Windows for more than 30 seconds at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by switching to `sounddevice` instead of `pyaudio` in Python 3. I also use the InputStream with a callback, all of which are running on a thread and the high CPU usage problem doesn't seem to be triggered. So I don't think using the InputStream class or the top function for recording directly would matter.